# How to read file size of /proc/cmdline

Tags: c, linux, file, filestream

I have

```c
FILE *file = fopen("/proc/cmdline", "r");
struct stat st;
fstat(file, &st);
char buffer[st.st_size];
fgets(buffer, st.st_size,file);
printf("%s", buffer);
```

By luck this prints out the contents of cmdline but I have an int pointer conversion warning at the `fstat()` function. If I try `fstat(fileno(file), &st);` the buffer has gibberish meaning st.st_size wasn't properly set. Like wise seeking to the end of file to get it's size also is not setting the size of the buffer properly

It seems st.st_size contains a number with a leading zero eg 01315 hence gibberish out put

Comment: You cannot read the size of this file, or in heneral of anything in /proc, other than by reading the file to the end.

Comment: fseek to end also doesn't work prints out gibberish, so does it mean I am stuck ignoring pointer int conversion?

Comment: What pointer int conversion? Read `man stat`. It specifically mentions files in `/proc`. You read the file byte by byte or block by block until the end, like you would do with any file that is not a regular disk file.

Comment: `fstat(file, &st); ` compiler complains that file here should be an int

Comment: Why do you think `fstat()` takes a `FILE` pointer?

Comment: `fstat` takes an open file descriptor, not a `FILE` pointer. A file descriptor is something returned by an `open` system call (not `fopen`). Alternatively you could use `stat`. But don't bother, it will not work anyway, the returned size will be 0.

Comment: @Shawn `fstat(int fd` wasn't working so I tried `fstat(file` and it worked but the compiler wasn't happy

Comment: "it worked" You are rather seriously mistaken.

Comment: `fstat(int fd`... Um. You should go back and review how to call functions in C.

Comment: @Shawn I just meant passing fd as a parameter not int fd

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I will send a snippet so you see for yourself

Comment: What for? To convince me that "it worked"? No thank you very much. You just got lucky. `st` contained garbage before your failed call to `fstat` and it contained the same garbage after the failed call (you never checked whether `fstat` succeeded). TL;DR (1) If the compiler says that there is a problem in your code, then chances are that *there is a problem in your code* and you need to solve it before you ever try to run the code. (2) If a function returns an error code, you check it, always, no excuses.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI You are correct that in general, stat will report a size of 0 for files in /proc because their size cannot be determined before the the file is read. But there are exceptions. /proc/cmdline is one such exception where the contents can be determined before the file is read and stat will report its actual size, at least for current kernels.

Comment: @IanAbbott I've tried it and I've got 0.

Comment: @IanAbbott https://godbolt.org/z/8f3G5WacM , same on my local machine.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI It has non-zero size since Linux kernel v6.2. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2/source/fs/proc/cmdline.c#L20

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI But of course user code dealing with /proc/cmdline should ignore a reported size of 0 and read the file anyway when running on pre-6.2 kernels.

Comment: @IanAbbott 6.2 is too new for me. And why would user code need the size from struct stat anyway? It's not like there is no other way to read a file.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI For people who don't know how to read a file unless they can introduce a race condition by relying on the size of the file taken before they read it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to read file size of /proc/cmdline

(Assuming Linux) like so (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
#include <limits.h>
...

char buf[ARG_MAX];
FILE *fp = fopen("/proc/cmdline", "rb");
size_t len = fread(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, fp);
```